# chromecast closed captioning with HLS (.m3u8)

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am looking for an example that enables captions that are embedded in an HLS stream (.m3u8).  The examples on GitHub regarding captions all use a stand-alone caption file.  Is it possible to use the caption file that is embedded in the .m3u8?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

See: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Player#enableCaptions

Example:

If you have CEA-608 captions embedded in your HLS stream you can use

`enableCaptions(true, cast.player.api.CaptionsType.CEA608);`